# Can't I select from actual table and the declared table at the same time? SQL ERROR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some tables already declared and did some work.

My final state is..

```
declare @tmptblC table(
rowIndex int identity(1,1) not null,
Officer varchar(40),
Date varchar(20),
Total_Served int,
Total_Serving_Time varchar(16),
Avg_Serving_Time varchar(16),
Log_In_Time varchar(16),
Log_Off_Time varchar(16),
Served_by_Hour int,
Total_Tran_Served int,
Total_Tran_Time varchar(16),
Avg_Tran_Time varchar(16),
Avg_Tran_Per_Cus float);
```

I declared the @tmptblC table

```
declare @dt datetime;
set @dt=cast('01-01-1980' as datetime);
insert into @tmptblC
select
loginname as 'Officer',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), regdate, 105) as 'Date',
count(distinct(queueno)) as 'Total_Served',
CONVERT(varchar(6), sum(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime))/3600)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (sum(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 3600) / 60), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), sum(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 60), 2) as 'Total_Serving_Time',
CONVERT(varchar(6), avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime))/3600)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 3600) / 60), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 60), 2) as 'Avg_Serving_Time',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), min(nexttime), 108) as 'Log_In_Time',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), max(nexttime), 108) as 'Log_Off_Time',
isnull(nullif(3600/datediff(second, @dt,
cast(('01-01-1980 '+
cast(CONVERT(varchar(6), avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime))/3600)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 3600) / 60), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), avg(datediff(second,nexttime,endtime)) % 60), 2) as varchar(30)))
 as datetime)),0),0) as 'Served_by_Hour',
sum(matter_served) as 'Total_Tran_Served',
CONVERT(varchar(6), sum(matter_time)/3600)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (sum(matter_time) % 3600) / 60), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), sum(matter_time) % 60), 2) as 'Total_Tran_Time',
CONVERT(varchar(6), avg(matter_time)/3600)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (avg(matter_time) % 3600) / 60), 2)+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), avg(matter_time) % 60), 2) as 'Avg_Tran_Time',
round(sum(matter_served)/cast(count(distinct(queueno)) as float),1) as 'Avg_Tran_Per_Cus'
from @tmptblB
group by loginname, regdate
```

I insert into @tmptblC.

```
select * from @tmptblC
```

I can get the results from @tmptblC.

But..

When I do this,

```
select logincode from login, @tmptblC where @tmptblC.rowIndex=1 and login.contents=@tmptblC.officer
```

I got this error.

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 109
Must declare the scalar variable "@tmptblC".
```

So I start doubting as `login` table is the actual table and `@tmptblC` is the one i created just for this query.

Can't they be used together?

If that's the case, wht's the solution.

Tkz.

I found out that if I do

```
select logincode from login, @tmptblC
```

it is ok.. which means..

```
@tmptblC.rowIndex=1 and login.contents=@tmptblC.officer
```

is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias table variables in order to refer to them in other parts of the query (such as a join condition). The parser still doesn't seem to understand that the `@` prefix might refer to a table variable despite the fact that they have existed since SQL Server 2000 (Edit: [But it looks like this may not be a straightforward change to make](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/329692/table-variable-inconsistent-brackets-required-or-not))!

```
select logincode
 from login 
join @tmptblC [@tmptblC]
on login.contents=[@tmptblC].officer
 where [@tmptblC].rowIndex=1
```

To answer the question in the comments about updates (you would only need to use this if your update requires a join otherwise just refer to the column names unqualified) example syntax is

```
declare @t1 table (c1 int,c2 int)
declare @t2 table (c1 int,c2 int)

insert into @t1 values(1,NULL)
insert into @t2 values(1,105)

UPDATE t1
SET t1.c2 = t2.c2
FROM @t1 t1 JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1

SELECT * FROM @t1
```

Comment: Then.. what abt updating? will it be like update @tmptblC [@tmptblC] But it says incorrect syntax by doing so.